# gmake ifeq comparison does not give desired result

Tags: compilation, makefile, conditional-statements, gnu-make

I have a somewhat complex makefile that I want to change and I don't know much about make.

```
BUILD_TYPE = SERVER

BAS_CSRC = a.c \
           b.c \
           c.c
```

What I want to do is conditionally add things to BAS_CSRC like so:

```
ifeq ($(BUILD_TYPE), SERVER)
USR_CSRC    =  $(BAS_CSRC) \
           d.c \
           e.c
endif

all_csrc     =  $(USR_CSRC) $(foreach var, $(COMMON_OBJECTS), $($(var)_csrc))
```

But when I compile the d.c and e.c are just ignored so the ifeq fails. Why? What about quoting?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've typed here it should work (and I cut and pasted this into a test makefile which worked for me), which likely means there's something different about your real environment, than this example.  Can you show us where you use the variable `all_csrc`?  Maybe it's that that's the problem, not the assignment of the variable.

Make sure you don't have any trailing whitespace.  Make sure you have matching case in your variables and values (make, like all UNIX tools, is case-sensitive).  You can try adding `$(info ...)` statements to your makefile and it will print out what it's doing.  Put one inside the `ifeq` to see if it fires, and after the `endif` to see what the value of `USR_CSRC` is.

Also, in general it's not a good idea to add whitespace into if statements or function calls like `foreach`.  In the above situations it shouldn't matter but in general it's best avoided.